# Use jQuery to scroll a long vertical form

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, scroll

I have a long vertical data entry form in my app. As you tab through the form and reach the bottom of the visible part of the page, the page only scrolls the current focused field into view (the focus always remains at the bottom of the screen). It is annoying because you can never see the next field you're going to focus into. I would love to use jQuery to automatically scroll the focused field to the top of the window when it gets the focus (but only when it wasn't in the visible area before getting the focus). Anybody seen a plugin or know how to get me started?

Answer (score 1):

There's an HTML Element method called "scrollIntoView" that does exactly what you want.  (May not work on older browsers, but I tested it with IE9, Firefox3, and Chrome).

Alternatively, you could likely use jquery's .offset() and .scrollTop() functions to get/set the scroll position of the document and the element at hand.

```
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        function OnFocus(evt) {
            this.scrollIntoView(true);
        }

        window.onload = function (evt) {
            $("input").focus(OnFocus);
        };

    </script>

</head>


<body>

<input type="text" id="text1" value="text1"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="text2" value="text2"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="text3" value="text4"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="text4" value="text5"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="text5" value="text6"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="text6" value="text6"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="text7" value="text7"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="text8" value="text8"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="text9" value="text9"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>
...
<input type="text" id="text34"/> <p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>
```

Comment: scrollIntoView always keeps the focused field at the top which is not exactly what I'm looking for...especially since my field labels are located above the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not exactly what I wanted, I decided to added the following to certain elements of the page.

```
function ScrollToTop(object) {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(object).offset().top - 30 }, 1000, 'linear');
}
```

And then on certain elements:

```
 onfocus="ScrollToTop(this);"
```

I was hoping to not hard-code the focus events. It would be nice if there were a "scrollingIntoView" event that I could bind to and then run my script. Anyway, my solution is nice and elegant.